# Count within dataframe subsets on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, subset

From the following dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'In':['A','B','D','Z','Q','E'],
                   'Out' : ['Z', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'Z', 'A'],
                   'Score_in' : ['6', '2', '1', '0', '1', '3'], 
                   'Score_out' : ['2','3','0', '1','1','3'],
                   'Place' : ['One','Two','Four', 'Two','Two','One']})
```

I would choose, for instance, "A" wherever it appears ("In" and "Out" as well) in order to get its total of "score_in" and "score_out" and to correlate its scores to "Place".

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: something like: {A:(in_score+out_score, score.corr("place"))}.. I would like to get the sum of scores and if it is significantly correlated to a place, for instance the one where occurrences for A are max.

Comment: @Nate Please follow Quang's suggestion and edit your question with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total score in and out for each In or Out, you can try using groupby:

```py
df.groupby('In').Score_in.sum().add(
    df.groupby('Out').Score_out.sum(), 
    fill_value=0)
```

I think you should use integers in 'Place' instead of strings if you want to run correlations afterwards

Comment: Thank you Hugolm, but I meant something slightly different: if I have d1= df.groupby(['In'])[['Score_in', 'Score_out']].sum() and d2= df.groupby(['Out'])[['Score_in', 'Score_out']].sum(), I would like to get for each team the following result=d1[0]+d2[1], which I cannot have with this syntax. Any help?

Comment: Check my edit. You apply the groupby for in and out, and only keep score_in and score_out respectively. Then, you add them together, with `fill_value=0` to avoir having issues with index in one dataframe but not in the other

Comment: thank you! Should I get just one team from the output?

Comment: I don't understand your question, you want to know the total score for one given team ?

Comment: Yes, I would. Moreover, I was wondering on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589067/pandas-subset-parameterization
can you help me?

Comment: All you have to do is to add ['A'] if you want score from team A. I will check your other issue