# Selecting column after groupby without using explicit column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming

With the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['26-12-2018','26-12-2018','27-12-2018','27-12-2018','28-12-2018','28-12-2018'],
                   'In':['A','B','D','Z','Q','E'],
                   'Out' : ['Z', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'Z', 'A'],
                   'Score_in' : ['6', '2', '1', '0', '1', '3'], 
                   'Score_out' : ['2','3','0', '1','1','3'],
                   'Place' : ['One','Two','Four', 'Two','Two','One']})
```

I would like to code groupby rules on a generic form in order to try parameterizing subsets creation.
For instance, instead of the following:

```
df.groupby('In').Score_in.sum()
```

I suppose my desired output would be something like #1 or #2 with `df.columns[]` or `.iloc[:,[]]` syntaxes like:

```
df.groupby(df.columns[1]).df.iloc[:,[3]].sum() #1
df.groupby(df.iloc[:,[0]]).df.iloc[:,[3]].sum() #2
```

Of course, none of the above syntaxes works. Any help?

Comment: for "groupby rules" I mean simple groupby sintax. The fact is that it is affected by column name (original or renamed) of a given dataset (in my example, "In" and Score_in). My final output is to delete this direct link to the name and to make more general one on the columns slicing properties like the syntaxes #1 or #2 (which don't work). To summarize: are there correct syntaxes to express #1 or #2 semantics in order to have the same output of df.groupby('In').Score_in.sum()?

Comment: Do you know the name of the column you want to keep beforehand ? Or you only know its position in the DataFrame ?

Comment: I know just its position in the DataFrame

Comment: Yes, you can use generic parameters much like what @Hugolmn solution is showing.  However, I would stay away from using the dot notation for filtering columns like you are show in your post. Use `df['colname']` over `df.colname` it is safer and more versatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is not with the groupby, it's about how you keep a particular column afterwards. `groupby` has no `df` attribute, so it can't work this way.

Here is a piece of code that works as expected:

```py
df.groupby(df.columns[1])[df.columns[3]].sum()

In  Score_in
A   6
B   2
D   1
E   3
Q   1
Z   0
```

Notice: I casted Score_in and Score_out as integers or else the groupby would'nt work.

Comment: Thank you Hugolmn! I put Score_in and Score_out .to_numeric and it seems to work too.

Comment: `to_numeric` will basically cast as int or float, depending on the input :)